# strtotime - a second before midnight

Tags: php

I attempted this:

```
$date_string = strtotime('6 Mar, 2011 23:59:59');
```

But I think PHP can't interpret that for some reason as it returned empty. I tried this:

```
$date_string = strtotime('6 Mar, 2011 midnight');
```

The above worked but I need it to be a second before midnight i.e. the last second of the day. How can I get strtotime to return this without changing the 6 Mar, 2011 part?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works for me if I use `March 6, 2011 23:59:59`. Any chance of changing the input format?

Other than that, you could of course subtract 1 second from the timestamp. Note however that you need to use March 7:

```
$date_string = strtotime('7 Mar, 2011 midnight') - 1;
```

Comment: Its possible to change the format but it will be a bit of a pain to do so. Its strange how `strtotime` works on the date part but added with the time part it doesn't work. Maybe I can `strtotime` the date part, pass to `date()` to format it your way and then bring it back to strotime again - hmm seems a little inefficient? But will work, I guess.

Comment: My above commenting of changing the format to something like Pekka's worked for me. I think I'll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 14):

Hope this helps.  I used this and it gives todays timestamp just before midnight.  Counter intuitive.

```
$today_timestamp =  strtotime('tomorrow - 1 second');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `mktime`?

```
mktime(23,59,59,3,6,2011);
```

Comment: I don't really want to change my date format or do any parsing, if I have to, I was hoping it to be very minimal!

Answer (score 2):

If you're on PHP 5.3 or greater, you could use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

The [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function allows you to manually specify how to parse your input date string.

```
$date = '6 Mar, 2011 23:59:59';
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y H:i:s', $date)->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Sweet, DateTime looks awesome, must start using